# Position html element relative to another to stop elements jumping around

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a site where I have written some javascript to create a 'typewriter' type effect for the large middle centered text seen below. The script animates the text so that it types forward letter by letter and then deletes the text before starting a new word. The problem I'm having is that when the text is deleted the paragraph element containing the text is empty and the button below 'jumps' to the position where the text was. I'd like to know a good way to fix this issue, either in the javascript or with a simple css positioning fix. I wondered if there was maybe a way to position the button relative to the top "we create digital products text"?

[image: typeWriter effect]

[image: button jumps up]

This is my html:

```
<div class="agency-hero">
    <section class="container">
      <div class="hero-text customFadeInUp">
        <h1 class="tagLine">
          We create digital products
        </h1>
        <p><span class="txt-type " data-wait="2000" data-words='[" "," Websites "," Web Applications "]'></span></p>
        <a href="agency-portfolio-4.html" class="stayPut">
          See our work
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

and the javascript to animate the text:

```
const TypeWriter = function(txtElement, words, wait = 3000){
    this.txtElement = txtElement;
    this.words = words;
    this.txt='';
    this.wordIndex=0;
    this.wait=parseInt(wait,10);
    this.type();
    this.isDeleting = false;
}

// Type Method
TypeWriter.prototype.type = function() {

    //current index of word
    const current = this.wordIndex % this.words.length;
    //get Full text
    const fullTxt = this.words[current];
    //check for if currently in the deleting state or not
    if(this.isDeleting){
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0,this.txt.length -1);
    }else{
        //add a character
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0,this.txt.length +1);
    }

    //insert txt into element
    this.txtElement.innerHTML = `<span class="txt">${this.txt}</span>`;

    // Initial Type Speed
    let typeSpeed = 300;

    if(this.isDeleting){
        typeSpeed /= 2;
    }

    // If word is complete then move on to next word
    if(!this.isDeleting && this.txt == fullTxt){
        //make pause at the end
        typeSpeed = this.wait;
        //set Delete to True
        this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if(this.isDeleting && this.txt == ''){
        this.isDeleting=false;
        //move to next word
        this.wordIndex ++;
        // Pause before start typing
        typeSpeed = 500;
    }
    setTimeout(() => this.type(),typeSpeed);
}
// Init on DOM Load

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);

//Init App

function init(){
    const txtElement = document.querySelector('.txt-type');
    const words = JSON.parse(txtElement.getAttribute('data-words'));
    const wait = txtElement.getAttribute('data-wait');

    new TypeWriter(txtElement, words, wait);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS property min-height to maintain the desired gap between both texts. Take a look at the below codes.

**With Text-**

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  color:black;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color:red;
  min-height:20px;
}
p+p {
  font-size: 20px;
   background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<h1>We create Digital Products</h1>
<p>Type Writer</p>
<p>See my work</p>
```

**Without Text**

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  color:black;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color:red;
  min-height:20px;
}
p+p {
  font-size: 20px;
   background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<h1>We create Digital Products</h1>
<p></p>
<p>See my work</p>
```

p is a block element and its height is getting calculated on the basis of its content. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for relative positioning you use the css position property with a value of relative and use the top and left properties to change it. However, you could also use transform to change the positions.

For example:

```css
button {
  position:relative;
  top:50vh;
}
//Or
button {
  transform: translate(0, 50vh);
}
```

you can change these depending on how you want it.
In my opinion, if I read it correctly, it looks like you want to keep it there so I'd use absolute positioning.

Such as:

```css
button {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:90vh;
  //This won't move no matter what
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give your `<p>` a defined height:

```css
.hero-text p {
    height: 20px;
}
```

```js
const TypeWriter = function(txtElement, words, wait = 3000){
    this.txtElement = txtElement;
    this.words = words;
    this.txt='';
    this.wordIndex=0;
    this.wait=parseInt(wait,10);
    this.type();
    this.isDeleting = false;
}

// Type Method
TypeWriter.prototype.type = function() {

    //current index of word
    const current = this.wordIndex % this.words.length;
    //get Full text
    const fullTxt = this.words[current];
    //check for if currently in the deleting state or not
    if(this.isDeleting){
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0,this.txt.length -1);
    }else{
        //add a character
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0,this.txt.length +1);
    }

    //insert txt into element
    this.txtElement.innerHTML = `<span class="txt">${this.txt}</span>`;

    // Initial Type Speed
    let typeSpeed = 300;

    if(this.isDeleting){
        typeSpeed /= 2;
    }

    // If word is complete then move on to next word
    if(!this.isDeleting && this.txt == fullTxt){
        //make pause at the end
        typeSpeed = this.wait;
        //set Delete to True
        this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if(this.isDeleting && this.txt == ''){
        this.isDeleting=false;
        //move to next word
        this.wordIndex ++;
        // Pause before start typing
        typeSpeed = 500;
    }
    setTimeout(() => this.type(),typeSpeed);
}
// Init on DOM Load

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);

//Init App

function init(){
    const txtElement = document.querySelector('.txt-type');
    const words = JSON.parse(txtElement.getAttribute('data-words'));
    const wait = txtElement.getAttribute('data-wait');

    new TypeWriter(txtElement, words, wait);
}
```

```css
.hero-text p {
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="agency-hero">
    <section class="container">
      <div class="hero-text customFadeInUp">
        <h1 class="tagLine">
          We create digital products
        </h1>
        <p><span class="txt-type " data-wait="2000" data-words='[" "," Websites "," Web Applications "]'></span></p>
        <a href="agency-portfolio-4.html" class="stayPut">
          See our work
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```